# Calculation of NashEquilibria in the selfish routing problem

Tags: game-theory

How should I go for estimating the NE in this problem:

[image]

I see how to estimate that the optimal is $1/2$ for both trips, however I also see why rational players are incentivized to deviate from such setting, but I don't see how to formalize this as "equation" that I can then derivate and show that the NE is indeed that 100% of people take the second route